# How to find and replace a name containing a number and store that number in a var?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a var like this:

> var text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, **{img3}** consectetur adipiscing elit."

I need to replace (**{img3}**) with an html tag,
 but I need to know the number *(In the example 3, but could have been any other number)* to match it.

```
text = text.replace(/{img[0-9]+}/g, "<img src='imageName" + [0-9] + "'>");
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Simon: unrelated to this one: http://jsfiddle.net/7GKY3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to make a reference to an array number with $1. For example, if $1 = 3, I want to get the third value in my array.

Yes it's possible to take a function as the second argument in [`#String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace),

**Note:** `m1` is the captured value from the regular expression. I subtracted `-1` from `m1` where `11` is my first array element, just remove that part if you want a `0` index.

```
var text  = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, {img3} consectetur adipiscing elit.";
var array = [11, 20, 57, 15, 25, 66];

text = text.replace(/{img(\d+)}/g, function(s, m1) {
     return "<b>" + array[m1-1] + "</b>"; #return <img> tag code here.
})
```

Returns:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 57 consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

Comment: I suppose this is what you were asking?

Answer (score 2):

You need to capture digits after `{img` in a matching group and reuse it in repalcement:

```
text = text.replace(/{img(\d+)}/g, "<img src='imageName$1'>");
// => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <img src='imageName3'> consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

Comment: Brilliant! But what can I do if I need to pass $1 in a var like so: "<img src='"+ array[$1] +"'>"?

Comment: I tried with eval and some concatenation twist, but I can't seems to use $1 in an Array:S

Comment: Do you mean, you want a value from the array to be put in as $1?

Comment: No, I want to make a reference to an array number with $1. For example, if $1 = 3, I want to get the third value in my array.

Comment: @Simon Arnold See answer below. If that is what your asking.